# How to fix IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, error-handling, wait

I am running into an IllegalMonitorStateException in my code and am not sure why I am receiving it and how to fix it. My current Code is and the error is happening in the try block:

```
  public static String scrapeWebsite() throws IOException {

    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(s);
    final HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(0);
    final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByValue(">");
    final HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
    try {
    page2.wait(1);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
      System.out.println("error");
    }
    String originalHtml = page2.refresh().getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
    return originalHtml;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this is because `page2.wait(1);`
you need to synchronize(lock) the `page2` object then call the wait. also for sleeping it's better to use `sleep()` method.

```
synchronized(page2){//page2 should not be null
    page2.wait();//waiting for notify
}
```

the above code will not throw the `IllegalMonitorStateException` exception.

and note that like `wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()` need to synchronize the object before notifying.

this [link](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#syncblock) may help about the explanation.

Comment: The mention of `sleep()` is a small aside right now. Maybe you can expand on that point?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I really don't know what is going to be happened! maybe `wait(1)` is an example of code, maybe it really wants to `wait()` with a timeout for `notify()`, I just mention the problem dude :)

Comment: @JohnKugelman Good catch, thanks for the point, I updated the answer, I just mixed up something :) thanks buddy, I own you a coffee

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to just pause for a second, [`Object.wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) is the wrong method. You want [`Thread.sleep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) instead.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1);  // Pause for 1 millisecond.
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
```

- `sleep()` pauses the current thread for the specified interval. Note that the time is specified in milliseconds, so 1 means 1 millisecond. To pause for 1 second pass 1000.
- `wait()` is a synchronization-related method used to coordinate activity among different threads. It needs to be called from inside a `synchronized` block in tandem with some other thread calling `notify()` or `notifyAll()`. It should **not** be used to simply add a delay to your program.